# How To Combine 2 Jquery Codes Into One

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, join, merge

I need a help to combine 2 jquery codes into one. I will use both codes on same page. This is my basic HTML code:

```
<div class="filter">
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="one" />One</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="two" checked="checked" />Two</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="three" />Three</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="four" checked="checked" />Four</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="five" />Five</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="six" checked="checked" />Six</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="seven" checked="checked" />Seven</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="eight" />Eight</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="nine" checked="checked" />Nine</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="ten" />Ten</label>
</div>
```

This is the first jquery code:

```
$(function() {
    var list = $("div.filter");
    var origOrder = list.children();
    var i, checked = document.createDocumentFragment();
    var unchecked = document.createDocumentFragment();
    for (i = 0; i < origOrder.length; i++) {
    if (origOrder[i].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].checked) {
            checked.appendChild(origOrder[i]);
        } else {
            unchecked.appendChild(origOrder[i]);
        }
    }
    list.append(checked).append(unchecked);
});
```

...and this is the second one:

```
$(function() {
    var list = $("div.filter");
    var origOrder = list.children();
    list.on("click", ":checkbox", function() {
        var i, checked = document.createDocumentFragment();
        var unchecked = document.createDocumentFragment();
        for (i = 0; i < origOrder.length; i++) {
            if (origOrder[i].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].checked) {
                checked.appendChild(origOrder[i]);
            } else {
                unchecked.appendChild(origOrder[i]);
            }
        }
        list.append(checked).append(unchecked);
    });
});
```

Here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vNHMv/) link.
Thank you.

Comment: What's the problem? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the click handler and the other script are essentially the same code, you could turn one of them into a function and refer to it by name.

```
$(function() {
    var list = $("div.filter");
    var origOrder = list.children();

    function doWhateverThisDoes() {
        var i, checked = document.createDocumentFragment();
        var unchecked = document.createDocumentFragment();
        for (i = 0; i < origOrder.length; i++) {
            if (origOrder[i].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].checked) {
                checked.appendChild(origOrder[i]);
            } else {
                unchecked.appendChild(origOrder[i]);
            }
        }
        list.append(checked).append(unchecked);
    }

    list.on('click', ':checkbox', doWhateverThisDoes);
    doWhateverThisDoes();
});
```

Comment: +1 for the function name humor